# Implementing signed adder in HDL

Tags: vhdl, verilog

Hey Everyone,
                I'm working on a project which requires me to use signed adders.
How does one implement this adder in HDL without using the arithmetic operators?(test bench not required), is there a way to modify an existing adder circuit to work as a signed adder, if so your inputs will be of great help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: *How does one implement this adder in HDL* - The same way as one implements *any* logical circuit. Start with the truth table.

Comment: StackOverflow should be your last resort. Define what you have to do, with discrete steps and then search and learn for each one of them. In a nutshell, do your homework. Then if you still have questions post them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question, you need to implement (for example) a *ripple carry adder*, which is a series of *full adders* connected in a certain way. There will be tons of stuff about this on the internet, because it is standard stuff. For example: http://eda-playground.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code-examples/full-adder.html

To answer the second part of your question: an adder which can handle signed numbers is identical to one that can only handle unsigned numbers as long as the inputs and outputs use *two's complement* representation.

To negate a number using two's complement representation, one inverts all the bits and adds one. For example, using an 8-bit two's complement representation

```
 23  is  00010111    and
-23  is  11101001    which was generated by inverting all the bits (11101000) and then adding 1
```

now let's add the two together using a standard adder, ie by doing long addition as you would have learnt at school:

```
 23  is  00010111 
-23  is  11101001 +
         --------
      (1)00000000
         --------
```

Look: it works! The `(1)` is the carry output, which you can ignore. The result of adding two numbers needs to be one bit wider than the wider of those two numbers. So, really we should have widened the two inputs to 9-bit first. So, in a 9-bit two's complement representation:

```
 23  is  000010111 
-23  is  111101001 +
         ---------
      (1)000000000
         ---------
```

You widen numbers which use a two's complement representation (i.e., *signed* numbers) by *sign-extending*: that is, you take the left hand bit (the MSB, the *sign bit*) and repeat it leftwards (in this case once, because we are widening by just 1 bit).

Comment: Thank you ,  is there a way of implementing this without using the "+"  operator.